# Limit the number of console outputs in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I tried to print json data to the Chrome console, but the maximum number of messages was limited to 1000.
Is there any substitute or lifting this restriction?
The output of some content is repeated and I want to know only the type of output.

Comment: Since Chromium is open source, you can sift through all the files and edit it to as you wish. However, it will cause significant slow downs if it reaches a high amount because of low memory. It might just be easier to write the output to a file instead.

Comment: I want to do the opposite! Keep memory down. Chrome just chokes when I leave dev console open - so I was looking for possible ways to reduce memory. Especially if I go away for an hour - come back and it's all crashed.