# has maximum number of lines in chrome console increased?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools, debug-console

There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64816224/limit-the-number-of-console-outputs-in-chrome-developer-tools) which states that the number of lines in the chrome developer console is 1000. I experienced this a few months ago and excess lines were discarded slightly randomly. Yesterday I seemed to hit a limit at about 1500 lines (I think). Today I have a log with over 6500 lines and no discards. Was I dreaming? Am I dreaming? Or has the number of lines that chrome stores and displays increased?